# Options doesn't show up when hardware menu is pressed

Tags: java, android

I have 2 devices on which i am testing my application, a Galaxy Nexus and a Desire HD (which has hardware buttons)

I am implementing the menu like this

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.feedback:

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " feedback");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "");
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.about:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

On the galaxy nexus the action bar menu button shows up, and it inflates the menu and everything works fine.
On the Desire HD in the action bar the menu button doesn't show up because i have hardware buttons, but if i press the hardware menu button nothing happens.

how can i fix this?

EDIT: this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/feedback"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="Feedback"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/about"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="About" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please post you menu XML in `activity_main.xml`. Are you using the `showAsAction` attribute?

Comment: Ok, i've added the xml to the main post, showAsAction is set to never because on my JB galaxy nexus i had feedback shown on the left of the menu button in the action bar, and i wanted it inside the menu

Comment: Are you using ActionBar Sherlock and what is you minimum API?

Comment: I followed this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html
my min sdk is 8 and target is 15. My desire HD has ICS and my galaxy nexus has JB

Comment: I don't see any reason why the menu doesn't show up on the Desire... Last guess: are you using an OnKeyListener that is intercepting the menu button?

Comment: I think that cannot be this but try to remove the line `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` maybe you are overwriting default behaviour in other place?

Comment: Nope, it should be default. BTW, sometimes i have problems with the back button too, actually i had to hardcode the back button to exit my app. 
So maybe the menu button isn't working aswel as it should?
Can i hardcode it to do the default action?
Or is there a fix to the buttons not working?

Comment: I am testing and i see that any button except "home" works in my apps, so i think it's not a coding problem, since this happens in all of my apps, i reposted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411904/only-the-home-button-works-in-my-apps
 so if any of you knows the answer please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i hardcode it to do the default action?

I'm still not sure why this is happening, but here is how to intercept the Menu button and open the Menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem temporarly, i hope i'll find a permanent solution to it