# Only the home button works in my apps

Tags: android

By default in my apps the back and menu buttons are not working, also the long press of the search button doesn't work. This only happens in my apps and it doesn't work either on my desire hd, emulator or galaxy nexus (software back button).

What could be the problem? 
Is this happening only to me?

To make the back button close my application i have to hardcode it

Comment: The buttons doesn't work in any of my apps, even a new project, so i don't think posting code will help